# calculating max error, $L^2$ and $H^1$ errors for numerical Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to calculate heat equation numerically using MATLAB

$ u_{i,j}= u_i,j+1 + \alpha (u_{i-1,j+1}-2u_{i,j+1}+u_{i+1,j+1})$

$\alpha=\frac{h^2}{k}$
I also trying to find the
max error and $H^1$ error  between exact and numerical solution for heat equation problem ? the error should reduced by factor 2 , when I calculted it I found that it reduced by factor 4.
Can Any one explain why this happen?

However I calculated also $L^2$  error between exact and numerical solution for heat equation problem and it reduced by factor 4 as expected.

Comment: What is your 'heat equation problem'?